# gae_mini_profiler {% profiler_includes %} gives Invalid block tag: 'profiler_includes'

Tags: django, google-app-engine, profiling, django-nonrel

I am attempting to install gae_mini_profiler in my django-nonrel app

I placed the `{% profiler_includes %}` tag at the bottom of my `base.html`

It results in a

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: Invalid block tag: 'profiler_includes'
```

I placed

```
from gae_mini_profiler import profiler
application = profiler.ProfilerWSGIMiddleware(application)
```

at the bottom of `djangoppengine/main/__init__.py`

I followed all the other instructions at https://github.com/kamens/gae_mini_profiler#start

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by changing `gae_mini_profiler/templatetags.py` to be a true template tag library.

To do this create a package called templatetags, and then move(and rename) the templatetags.py module to profiler_tags.py.

Inside of profiler_tags.py make the following changes:

Change:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
register = webapp.template.create_template_register()
```

To:

```
from django.template import Library
register = Library()
```

---

Change:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates/includes.html")
```

To:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../templates/includes.html")
```

---

In your settings file add gae_mini_profiler to your list of installed apps.

---

Remove all references to

```
template.register_template_library('gae_mini_profiler.templatetags')
```

---

In your templates whereever you had `{% profiler_includes %}` you then need to add a load block

```
 {% load profiler_tags %}
```

I think that is all of the changes, but need to go check my git log.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the new Python 2.7 runtime for GAE? If so, the django template setup is slightly different and gae_mini_profiler hasn't been upgraded yet (anyone is welcome to submit this fix, haven't gotten to it yet).

It should be easy to work around as the only thing you need to do is find a way to render the HTML string returned by `gae_mini_profiler.templatetags.profiler_includes()` anywhere in your page. There are a number of methods of accomplishing this if the built-in template tag isn't working as-is. You could simply call the function in your base request handler and pass the resulting html into your base template if absolutely necessary (although this is admittedly a gross hack).

We'll hopefully have Python 2.7 working w/ gae_mini_profiler shortly. If you're not on Python 2.7, I'm not sure what the issue is as I'd expect the current code to work...

Comment: you might find this bug in appstats relevant as well http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6448

Comment: @DataSurfer Yup, then that's the issue. If you drop to 2.5 everything will be fine, if not you can either try the quick workaround above or wait until we upgrade to 2.7 compatibility.

Comment: Wait, the unicode issue above is causing the invalid block tag error?  I only found it because appstats was not including the url path in the reports.

Comment: No, sorry -- Python 2.7 is the issue.

Comment: @Nix It's not solved in the repo yet, but the workaround above works: "It should be easy to work around as the only thing you need to do is find a way to render the HTML string returned by gae_mini_profiler.templatetags.profiler_includes() anywhere in your page. There are a number of methods of accomplishing this if the built-in template tag isn't working as-is. You could simply call the function in your base request handler and pass the resulting html into your base template if absolutely necessary (although this is admittedly a gross hack)."

Comment: I ended up making templatetags.py actually a templatetag library and then just included mini_profiler in my list of apps, and "loading" the library in my template.